# Shortcodes não funcionam no meu tema wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme, plugin-wordpress

Estou criando meu tema e esta tudo ok,

Mas instalei um plugin e não funciona corretamente quando adicionado shortcodes ao tema. Na pagina parece no console as tags html do plugin, mas fica um grande espaço em branco sem o slider, no site antes de aparecer o texto da página. Mudei de tema para ver se o problema era o plugin mas no outro tema funcionou perfeitamente. Achei que pudesse ser o jquery, mas com ou sem o jquery padrão do wordpress (no header ou footer) o resultado é o mesmo.

O que sera que estou fazendo errado?

function.php

```
<?php

require_once('inc/redux-framework-master/redux-framework.php');
require_once('inc/office-master-theme-options.php');


add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post','page' ) );

function enqueue_jquery() {

    wp_deregister_script('jquery' ); 


    wp_register_script( 
         'jquery', 
         get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js',
         array(), 
         '1.11.1', 
         false
    );


    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_jquery');



function enqueue_styles_scripts() {


    wp_enqueue_style(
        'style-theme',
        get_stylesheet_uri(),
        array('bootstrap-css')
    );


    wp_enqueue_style(
        'bootstrap-css',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    );


    wp_enqueue_style(
        'stylish-portfolio',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/css_adicional.css'
    );


    wp_enqueue_style(
        'font-awesome',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.css'

    ); 



    wp_enqueue_script(
        'bootstrap-js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js',null
    );


} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles_scripts');



function wpse_ie_conditional_scripts() { ?>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_ie_conditional_scripts' );





require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');
register_nav_menus( array(
     'primary' => __( 'Main Menu', 'THEMENAME' ),
) );


?>
```

page.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="article">
                    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                    <p><?php echo do_shortcode('[meta_gallery_slider]'); ?></p>
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <div class="article">
                    <p>Error 404</p>
                </div>          
            <?php endif; ?>



        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu tinha esquecido de inserir `<?Php wp_footer(); ?>` no arquivo `footer.php`

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer
>
> Examples
>
> In twentyten theme
>
> wp-content/themes/twentyten/footer.php:

```
<?php
   /* Always have wp_footer() just before the closing </body>
    * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
    * generally use this hook to reference JavaScript files.
    */
    wp_footer();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Tradução literal:

> Tenha sempre wp_footer() antes de fechar a tag  do seu tema, ou
>   você ira quebrar muitos plugins, que  geralmente usam esse hook para
>   referenciar os arquivos javascript